# How to improve IntelliJ code editor speed?

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ (Community Edition) for several months, and at first I'm pleased about its speed & simplicity. But now, after upgrading to version 10, it's extremely slow. Sometimes I click a file then it takes 5 - 15 seconds to open that file (it freeze for that time).

I don't know if I have done anything which cause that: I have installed 2 plugins(regex, sql), and have 2 versions of IntelliJ on my machine (now the version 9 removed, only version 10 remains).

Is there any tips to improve speed of code editor, in general, or specifically IntelliJ? I have some experience when using IntelliJ:

1. Should open IntelliJ a while before working, cause it needs time for indexing.
2. Don't open too many code tabs
3. Open as less other program as possible. I'm using 2 GB RAM WinXP, and it just seems fairly enough for Java, IntelliJ & Chrome at the same time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try to increase using memory size at `%IDEA_HOME%\bin\idea.exe.vmoptions`

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
```

- `Xms128m` means that at startup there will be allocated 128 mb for heap.
- `Xmx512m` means that maximum heap size available for IDEA is 512 mb
- `-XX:MaxPermSize=250m`  [PermGen](http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) related to java heap.

Also you can set maximum garbage collector pause

```
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
```

That means that java's GC will take max 10ms to do his work.

And use concurrent Mark-Sweep (CMS) Collector (But i'm not sure that this will help for latest version of IDEA)

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Comment: thanks, would you please provide me more information about how they works? Or a place where I can look up the options?

Comment: I don't know if that is the reason, but in fact the performance is a little better(it doesn't halt too long now). Could you please provide some explanation for your tips?

Comment: sorry, I don't know that you have updated the answer. It seems that stackoverflow doesn't notify it.

Comment: @hoang-long Better tell me what is you don't understand, then ill try explain better.

Comment: Official JetBrains position on JVM options tweaking: if IDEA is not fast enough, you should not waste time looking for the optimal set of the JVM options, but take a CPU snapshot and send it to us so that we can fix real problems.

Answer (score 9):

You should submit a CPU performance snapshot to the issue tracker as [described in the FAQ](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192).